# How to get messages from ActiveMQ using REST requests

Tags: rest, activemq-classic

I am sending message to queue using following request:

```
POST http://localhost:8161/api/message/PR?type=queue
Host: localhost:8161
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
User-Agent: curl/7.48.0
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 12
```

Then I go to the admin UI and I see the queue and the message there.

Now the question, how can I retrieve this message?

Comment: You can get messages from RSS feeds. Go to activemq monitor and check for RSS feeds.